# bootstrap modal hide from server side mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have implemented the bootstrap modal for edit.

So when below button gets clicked it fires the following jquery to open the modal.

```
<button class='btn btn-s green ajax-edit' type='button' data-url='/Customer/GetEditForm/5' data-toggle='modal'> edit </button>
```

And my jquery on click event is like below.
 //ajax demo:
            var $modal = $('#ajax-modal');

```
        $(document).on('click', '.ajax-edit, .ajax-add', function () {
            // create the backdrop and wait for next modal to be triggered
            $('body').modalmanager('loading');
            var el = $(this);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $modal.load(el.attr('data-url'), '', function () {
                    $modal.modal();
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
```

This basically calls MVC action which generates the html as partial view and gets rendered within this modal div.

However, I have started to put some server side validation when this action gets fired, and if validation fails, i would like to dismiss this modal.

What i tried, when I generate the HTML for the partialview that gets rendered in the modal window I tried render only below script to be rendered and fired when modal is popped up but no luck.. doesn't work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $('#modal').modal('hide');
//$('#modal').modal('toggle');
```

});

Basically what i want to achieve is I want to dismiss the modal and print some alert message indicating the validation has failed. am I on completely wrong track ?

Comment: Does not sound like a good ux to me. Any chance you can have validation on the client side as well (to provide instant validation and avoid opening the modal in the first place) ?

Comment: Why don't you use Ajax .. there you can toggle between success and error methods. You will have better control.. else if you want to go with `load` approach then simply you can add a if statement in your partial view and your entire HTML of partial view must go under if. The if will check if validation was success or not. Later in your Jquery you can check the partial view content length. If its 0 it means there was a error. So dismiss the modal. Hope you get the basic idea

Comment: yes i got an idea but how can i dismiss the modal ?

Comment: Client side validation can be easily modified and bypassed. So I am trying to implement the server side..  @cYrixmorten

Comment: @superted true, that is why I suggest having both. There should indeed be checks on the server as well. Regarding the modal, I would suspect JQuery to return an object when you create the modal. That object should have a dismiss method (sorry I can't give more accurate suggestion but am on my mobile atm)

Comment: What is the DOM of your modal? From what you write before the code, I'm thinking you may want to do `$('#ajax-modal').modal('toggle')`

Comment: I am using the below code to be rendered in the partial view but still doesn't work. 
@if (!Model.IsValid)
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ajax-modal').modal('toggle');
        });

    </script>

}